# Authenticating requests to external REST service

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm really new to web development, and I don't really have a good grip on the main concepts of web. However, I've been tasked with writing an asp.net application where users can search documents by querying an external RESTful web service. Requests to this REST service must be authenticated by HTTP Basic Authentication.

So far so good, I've been able to query the service using `HttpWebRequest` and `HttpWebResponse`, adding the encoded user:pass to the request's authorization header, deserialize the Json response and produce a list of strings with url's to the pdf documents resulting from the search.

So now I'm programmatically adding `HyperLink` elements to the page with these urls:

```
foreach (string url in urls) {

    HyperLink link = new HyperLink();
    link.Text = url;
    link.NavigateUrl = url;
    Page.Controls.Add(link);

}
```

The problem is that requests to these documents has to be authorized with the same basic http authentication and the same user:pass as when querying the REST service, and since I'm just creating links for the user to click, and not creating any `HttpWebRequest` objects, I don't know how to authenticate such a request resulting from a user clicking a link.

Any pointers to how I can accomplish this is very much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The user will have to authenticate themselves when they click the link, the browser should pop up a username and password box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to do the request server-side, as I think you're already doing, and then show the results embedded in your own pages, or just stream the result directly back to the users.

It's a bit unclear what it is you need (what are the links, what do you show the users, etc.), so this is the best suggesting I can do based on the info you give.

**Update**:
I would create a HttpHandler (an .ashx file in an ASP.NET project), and link to that, with arguments so you can make the request to the REST service and get the correct file, then stream the data directly back to the visitor. Here's a simple example:

```
public class DocumentHandler : IHttpHandler {

    public Boolean IsReusable {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
        // TODO: Get URL of the document somehow for the REST request
        // context.Request
        // TODO: Make request to REST service

        // Some pseudo-code for you:
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";

        Byte[] buffer = new WebClient().DownloadData(url);
        context.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

        context.Response.End();
    }
}
```

I hope you can fill in the blanks yourself.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply, I'm sorry for being unclear. From querying the REST service I'm able to produce a list of strings with url's to documents. So when a user search for say documents of type Invoice for a specified date, I'm a able to show him the invoices for that day as standard <a> elements. But your suggestion seems logical, any suggestions on how to stream the html/pdf directly back to the user from the response object?

Comment: The example I've given shows you a way of getting data (with the WebClient class and stream that directly to the user. You might need to use another class, not sure what requirements the remote service has for authentication. If this answers your question, please mark it as the reply :)

Comment: Thanks again, it certainly helped me in my efforts! But I couldn't use a buffer because of overflowexception, so I had to copy the httpwebresponse responsestream directly to the reponse.outputsteram without a buffer. Also I didn't make a handler, though I would like to attempt to. What are the benefits of doing so? I would like to mark the answer as accepted, but maybe I should wait until I get a chance to implement the httphandler?